# PhoneGap/Cordova: Error: The command "android" failed

Tags: cordova

I am new to Cordova.
I followed the [this tutorial](http://codingsquare.blogspot.in/2013/08/creating-cordova-3-android-project.html) to create an android project . but I am facing the following  error on MAC :

**ERROR: Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.**

I repeated updated the Android SDK and edited the PATH also ---

export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/abhisheksmacbook/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/abhisheksmacbook/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/**android**

Still error persists.. :( :(
Any help ?

```
Creating android project...
Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 

/Users/abhisheksmacbook/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed,             and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
at /Users/abhisheksmacbook/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:85:29
at _rejected (/Users/abhisheksmacbook/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
at /Users/abhisheksmacbook/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
at Promise.when (/Users/abhisheksmacbook/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/abhisheksmacbook/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
at /Users/abhisheksmacbook/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
at flush (/Users/abhisheksmacbook/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:282:30
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

Comment: Change this path abhisheksmacbook/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/android to abhisheksmacbook/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ and test

Comment: @DiveshSalian : I did without android first & then I tries with android.. Still error persists.

Comment: u have added the path in system variable or user variable ???

Comment: @DiveshSalian: I just hit this line in terminal:  export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/abhisheksmacbook/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/abhisheksmacbook/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/

Answer (score 0):

On mac: after editing the PATH variable in the `~/.bash_profile`, run `source ~/.bash_profile` and close **all** terminal windows.
Open terminal again, and creating/building android platform works fine.